# Python: Regular expression... not working?

Tags: python, regex

I have this code:

```
    # If the username isn't alpha-numerics (inc: _, -, ., )
    if re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9 _\-\.]+$', repName) == False:
        print 'DECLINE: '+repName
    else:
        print 'ACCEPTED: '+repName
```

And when i test it against this string: ɢᴀꜱᴛяɪᴄ (which is grabbed from a website)
I get this returned:

> ACCEPTED: É¢á´€êœ±á´›Ñ?Éªá´„

Why is this getting through? Also why does Python seem to change the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsuccessful `re.match` is not `False`. It is `None`.

But you can also try it this way:

```
if re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9 _\-\.]+$', repName):
    print 'ACCEPTED: '+repName
else:
    print 'DECLINE: '+repName
```

Comment: Well that was 2 hours of string encoding/decoding confusion made completley pointless due to such a simple mistake. Thank you! And not, at the same time. :D